Can't find all solutions to a trigonometric equation
I have a problem to solve: Plot the function $2 \cos(6x) \sin(3x)$ and graphically find the maximum and minimum points. Find the maximum and minimum points analytically. Compare the results.
My solution:
Plotting the function $2 \cos(6x) \sin(3x)$ and its derivative $6 \cos 6x \cos 3x -12 \sin 6x \sin 3x$ is straightforward (see graph below):
enter image description here
Finding the maxima and minima analytically as follows:
$6 \cos 6x \cos 3x -12 \sin 6x \sin 3x=0 \\ \cos 6x \cos 3x = 2 \sin 6x \sin 3x $
Let $A=3x$ and rewrite the last equation as:
$\cos 2A \cos A=2 \sin2A \sin A$
Use the identity $\sin 2A =2 \sin A \cos A$ to rewrite the last expression as:
$\cos 2A \cos A = 4 \sin^2 A \cos A$
Use the identity $\cos 2A =1- 2\sin^2 A $ to write the last expression as:
$(1- 2 \sin^2 A) \cos A = 4 \sin^2 A \cos A \\ 1 - 2 \sin^2 A  = 4 \sin^2 A \\ 1 = 4 \sin^2 A + 2 \sin^2 A \\ 6 \sin^2 A = 1 \\ \sin^2 A = \frac{1}{6} \\ \sin A = \pm \sqrt{ \frac{1}{6}} $
$\therefore \sin A = \pm 0.4082$
The first solution $\sin A=0.4082$ gives $A = 0.4205$ (radians)in quadrant 1.
The second solution gives $A = \pi -0.4205= 2.721$ (radians), in quadrant 2.
The third solution gives $A = \pi+ 0.4205= 3.562$ (radians) , in quadrant 3.
The fourth solution gives $A = 2 \pi -0.4205= 5.863$ (radians) , in quadrant 4.
These results apply to $A=3x$ so to get the maxima and minima for $x$, divide the results by $3$ to get:
$x = 0.140$ (radians) in quadrant 1.
$x = 0.907$ (radians) in quadrant 2.
$x = 1.187$ (radians) in quadrant 3.
$x = 1.954$ (radians)  in quadrant 4.
Compared with the graph, there are only four solutions.
$x=0.524$ and $x=1.571$ are missing.
What error have I made?
All help appreciated.

Welcome to MSE. What are those $\backslash$ doing in your post?

Didn't notice that until now. They are typos.

I've corrected your post - if you want to do the "line by line" typesetting, separate each equation with a double backslash "\".

You jumped from$$(1-2\sin^2(A))\cos(A)=4\sin^2(A)\cos(A)\label{a}\tag1$$to $(1-2\sin^2(A))=4\sin^2(A)$. This is not correct. From \ref{a}, what you can deduce is that $(1-2\sin^2(A))=4\sin^2(A)\color{red}{\text{ or }}\cos(A)=0$. So, you missed the points $\frac\pi6$ and $\frac\pi2$ (which turn out to be the points at which your function attains its minimal and its maximal value respectively).

Such a silly mistake to make. Thanks for pointing that out.

You lost solutions when you divided by $\cos x$ in $(1- 2 \sin^2 A) \cos A = 4 \sin^2 A \cos A$.
Here is an alternative solution...
$y=2 \cos 6x \sin 3x \\ y = 2 (1 - 2\sin^2 3x) \sin 3x \\ y= 2 \sin 3x (1-2 \sin^2 3x) \\ y = 2 \sin 3x - 4 \sin^3 3x$
Then $y' = 2 \sin 3x (3 \cos 3x) - 4 (3 \sin^2  3x (3 \cos 3x) \\ = 6 \sin 3x \cos 3x - 36 \sin^2 3x \cos 3x \\ = 6 \sin 3x \cos 3x (1-6 \sin 3x)$
Setting $y'=0$ we have $6 \sin 3x \cos 3x = 0$ or $1-6 \sin 3x=0$.  The second equation has the solutions you originally found, but $6 \sin 3x \cos 3x = 3 \sin 6x$, so we have $3\sin 6x = 0 \implies 6x  = {\pi k}$ or $x = \dfrac {\pi k}{6}$.
You can then determine which of the six solutions has the minima and maxima for the original function.
